# A "confirm" error occurs in the data table. How should I fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

I using to datatables columns in confirm. but('do you want cancel?') An error occurs in that part.
There is no error in the number, but the text is error. How should we change it?
in this my code

```
 'columns': [
                  {
                    "data": null,
                    "bSortable": false,               
                    "mRender": function (o) { if (o.check_flag == 3){ 
                      return '<form action="" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="idx" value="' +
                      o.po_id + '?' + o.po_point + '">
                     <input type="submit" onclick="if(!confirm('do you want cancel?')){return false;}" 
                      value="cancel"></form>';
                    }else{
                      return '<span>not cancel</span>';
                    }
                    }
                }
                ]
```

Comment: just escape the single quotes, or use a double quote

Comment: @Kevin I don't know how to write it. Can you teach me?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin said in the comments, escape the single quotes. I simply added `\'` to both ends of your confirmation text.

```js
 'columns': [
                  {
                    "data": null,
                    "bSortable": false,               
                    "mRender": function (o) { if (o.check_flag == 3){ 
                      return '<form action="" method="post" ><input type="hidden" name="idx" value="' +
                      o.po_id + '?' + o.po_point + '">
                     <input type="submit" onclick="if(!confirm(\'do you want cancel?\')){return false;}" 
                      value="cancel"></form>';
                    }else{
                      return '<span>not cancel</span>';
                    }
                    }
                }
                ]
```